# Android Loading data from sqlite database to populate UI spinners

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, roboguice, robospice

I am developing mobile application that simply acts as another access point for dealing with a web application. ( it uses the native interface of android and makes some calls to the remote server for synchronizing data ) and keeps some user oriented data on the local sqlite3 database.

In one of mine activities , the data populated in the spinners(not too much data) should be loaded from the database ( the reason for that is that this data  has to be configurable in the main web application administration part by wish of the web application )  and it's not appropriate to put the data in the usual string.xml string bundle.

I also want to be able to again load the data , when the user is changing the local ( currently thinking of only two languages to support ).

I have searched and read , may be too many articles and got really confused and that's why I am asking this question. ( I have read that using loader , that not using the CursorLoader implementation is pretty painful - refering to the LoaderEx project of CommonsWare and their comments for Loaders framework
and given the fact that  the usage of Content Providers for me is unnecessary , because I don't intentd to share that database with other applications and is unnecessary boiler plate code around my app ) .

I want my code be working handling orientation changes and of course the activities and fragments lifescycle. We have decided also to use the Roboguice library for dependancy injection.

At least from what I've read the Robospice project is primarily purpose for asynchronios operations that query a remote server , for an example through a REST servives, so that's not an option for me either.

Can you provide me with some guidelines?